# I'm creating a spigot plugin, and the config file that appears on my test server doesn't match the one in Intellij

Tags: java, config, minecraft, spigot

The part of my config file specifically is this:

```
Players:
  "examplePlayer1":
    - 10
    - 0
  "examplePlayer2":
    - 75
    - 3
```

That's what it looks like in Intellij, but when I package the plugin and put it in my test server, the config file looks like this:

```
Players:
- examplePlayer:
  - 10
  - 0
```

That's an older version that didn't work for a few reasons, so I changed it, but now the new config won't save to the server.

In my OnEnable method, I have this line:
`getConfig().options().copyDefaults();`

In my OnDisable method, I have:
`saveConfig();`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call
`saveDefaultConfig();`
in my OnEnable method... whoops